# Setting max fetch depth in hibernate jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 classes named A,B,C as follows :

Class A :

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private B b;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Class B :

```
@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private C c;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Class C:

```
@Entity
public class C implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    //Getters and Settters
}
```

when i use method :

```
em.find(A.class, a.getId());
```

hibernate generates following sql query :

```
Hibernate :
select
    a0_.id as id1_0_0_,
    a0_.b_id as b_id2_0_0_,
    b1_.id as id1_1_1_,
    b1_.c_id as c_id2_1_1_,
    c2_.id as id1_2_2_
from
    A a0_
left outer join
    B b1_
        on a0_.b_id=b1_.id
left outer join
    C c2_
        on b1_.c_id=c2_.id
where
    a0_.id=?
```

and loads all three objects but i don't want hibernate to goes that far.
i tried to set a max fetch dept for hibernate by setting

```
<property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="0"/>
```

so that hibernate just goes for one object of class A, but the generated sql query became this one :

```
Hibernate:
    select
        a0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        a0_.b_id as b_id2_0_0_
    from
        A a0_
    where
        a0_.id=?

Hibernate:
    select
        b0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        b0_.c_id as b_id2_1_0_
    from
        B b0_
    where
        b0_.id=?

Hibernate:
    select
        c0_.id as id1_2_0_,
    from
        C c0_
    where
        c0_.id=?
```

as it's clear, hibernate fetched all three objects again.

as the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html) says :

> max_fetch_depth : 
>   Sets a maximum "depth" for the outer join fetch tree for single-ended associations (one-to-one, many-to-one). A 0 disables default outer join fetching.

it just impacts the outer join not the max fetch depth generally.

is there any way that when try to fetch objects of A, hibernate just brings 1 level of association? ( i mean objects of A have b but b doesn't have c )

Comment: Make the association B.c lazy. I would even advise to make them **all** lazy, and to use ad hoc queries using fetch joins if you want to load some eagerly.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your comment but in that way, if i use em.find(B.class, b.getId()) the c object of b would be lazy and not loaded.i want to know is there any configuration that can be used to set the max dept hibernate goes?

Comment: @HassanMusavi, I believe make all associations lazy and use `EntityGrapgh` annotation instead.